# after adding packages in project, android is ok but ios crash during start in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm adding packages to my application.

```
flutter:
  sdk: flutter
http: ^0.12.0
shared_preferences: ^0.5.2
```

Successfully ran on Android device.
Then I was this command to build for iOS:

> flutter build ios

And successful building and installing in xcode.
But when running the app in a device I get this error:

```
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"



int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

@autoreleasepool {

return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));  **Thread 1: signal SIGABRT**

  }

}
```

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

**How can I fix it??**

Comment: ANy errors in xcode console, try `cd ios` and then `pod install` using terminal

Comment: have you `flutter clean`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do `flutter clean` and

go to `ios` folder by `cd ios`

then install pods by `pod install`

then try building ios module by `flutter build ios --release`.